# How to use Foremost to recover new file types of unknown footer?

Tags: data-recovery, file-recovery, file-types

### How to use [Foremost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foremost_(software)) to recover new file types of unknown footer?

##### For Example:

File types of `.PSD` and `.NEF`.

##### "New file types" of foremost means:

The `foremost` software does not natively support Photoshop (.PSD) and Nikon Electronic Format (.NEF) files as built-in formats. However, we can add their header signatures to the configuration file of `foremost`. It's important to note that both .PSD and .NEF files do not have fixed footer signatures to my knowledge.

##### Trying to solve the question:

To determine the header signature for a .PSD file, you can refer to the [.psd file header signature](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/#50577409_pgfId-1055726) (also available [here](https://file-extension.net/seeker/file_extension_psd)): `8BPS\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`.

To determine the header signature for a .NEF file, you can refer to the [.NEF file header signature](https://file-extension.net/seeker/file_extension_nef) (also available [here](http://lclevy.free.fr/nef/)): `\x49\x49\x2A\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00`.

To add these file types to the `/etc/foremost.conf` file, include their respective header signatures with a maximum file size of 2000000000 (2GB), and do not include a footer definition.

##### Result of the trial, length mismatch:

However, the recovered .PSD files are just a few MB. They are smaller than the original files, and there is no common byte sequence indicating the end of the file.

(I had assumed that a common byte sequence could be a `\x00` null byte or multiple null bytes.)

I had expected `foremost` to generate recovered files that were oversized, up to 2GB in size, but that did not.

##### Underlining concerns of the question:

- How does `foremost` determine the length (or the end) of a new file type when the footer signature is not provided?
- In general, how do files indicate their lengths on drives if the filesystem information is damaged or reformatted?

##### Restate the question:

All in all, how can new file types be properly added to the `foremost` configuration file if the footer signatures are unknown, such as with .PSD or .NEF files?